# PrestaShopDatabaseException, Unknown column 'uninstall' in 'field list'

Tags: prestashop

I use prestashop 1.1.6.2 and always when i would to install every modules, appears this:

PrestaShopDatabaseException

Unknown column 'uninstall' in 'field list'

```html
INSERT INTO `ps_module_access` (`id_profile`, `id_module`, `view`, `configure`, `uninstall`) (
    SELECT id_profile, 234, 1, 1, 1
    FROM ps_access a
    WHERE id_tab = (
     SELECT `id_tab` FROM ps_tab
     WHERE class_name = 'AdminModules' LIMIT 1)
    AND a.`view` = 1)

at line 791 in file classes/db/Db.php
786.         if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
787.             $dbg = debug_backtrace();
788.             WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
789.         } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
790.             if ($sql) {
791.                 throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
792.             }
793. 
794.             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
795.         }
796.     }
DbCore->displayError - [line 425 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 601 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->execute - [line 376 - classes/module/Module.php] - [1 Arguments]
ModuleCore->install - [line 437 - modules/sendinblue/sendinblue.php]
Sendinblue->install - [line 867 - controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php]
AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcessCallback - [line 1116 - controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php]
AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcess - [line 178 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 183 - override/classes/Dispatcher.php]
Dispatcher->dispatch - [line 58 - admin/index.php]
```

Why?

Comment: Version 1.1.6.2? Are you sure? This is very much outdated, I don't even remember this version, the oldest one I remember is 1.2.5, and it didn't have the webservice or an explicit exception handler, so I presume you meant v 1.6.2? Anyway, how did you install it, did you upgrade from an existing prestashop distribution or was it a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong code in your `override/classes/Dispatcher.php`.

You can fix the code (try to add `public $uninstall = 0;`), delete the file or disable all overrides.